# Selenium chrome driver scrape dynamically add attribute in element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I am new in selenium chrome driver. I am scraping ecommerce web site where i am scraping all products details from home page but in that page products image are loading dynamically(after 5-7 seconds when products loaded).
source code is like this

```
<img alt="product1" class="image" />
```

after 5-7 seconds

```
<img alt="product1" class="image" src="product image url" />
```

So i want to scrape that image `src` attribute value.

I tried by below way

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or

```
Thread.sleep(20000)
```

but i am failed
anybody help me for how to get image `src` attribute value?

Comment: Please share the application url with us as behavior of the application is unclear

Comment: @AkashChavda Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium's "FluentWait" is your friend

```
final WebElement imgWithSrc = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.of(10_000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.of(250, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
            .ignoring(ScriptTimeoutException.class)
            .until(d -> {
                final WebElement imgElement = d.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.image"));
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(imgElement.getAttribute("src"))) {
                    return imgElement;
                }
                return null;
            });
```

In the second line you see the max. wait of 10s, with polling every 250ms (third line)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
WebElement image = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
        .until(
                ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                        By.xpath("//img[@alt='product1'][@src]")
                )
        );
```

The above code means that the waiter will be polling your DOM for `10` seconds unless your DOM gets the element described in the `xpath`. This `[@src]` part of xpath means that we query the element having `src` attribute so no positive result would be returned unless the required attribute is assigned to an element.